# Image Recognition - pyautogui

Tags: python, image, image-recognition, pyautogui

I open up Calculator from window. I use the snipping tool to copy an image of the number 7 button. I paste the image into the paint software and save it as a png file and save it in a directory on my desktop.

I open up the calculator, use this code to locate where the image is on the screen. However the code return a blank space when normally it should return the position of the image on the screen. The first time I ran it, it gave me a coordination but the second time, it just shows me a blank space and I have been trying to figure out why. I kept doing it over and over, re-copied, re-saved the image and rerun the code and it's still the same result, blank. Was wondering what could be the reason.

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:\\Users\\js\\Desktop\\jsPython\\seven2.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check your path string.For example, this code runs fine:

```
import pyautogui
print(pyautogui.locateOnScreen("C:\Python27\source\pyautogui\images\startIcon.png"))
```

I think you've made a typo in your path string.
Even better solution is to use absolute path.For example :

```
 import pyautogui,os

print(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.abspath("images\startIcon.png")))
```